# Ambiguous error in inherite class c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

so i will give a small example of what is my problem,can someone help me resolve this:

```
class A
{
   virtual void show()=0;
};
class B:public virtual A
{
   void show(){/*content inside*/}
};
class C:public virtual A
{
   void show(){/*content inside*/}
};
class D:public B,public C
{
   void show(){/*content inside*/}
};
```

can someone help me in this ambiguous problem,because i want to use the function `show()` in all classes,and i didn't quite understand how to solve this.
the error im getting is:  error C2550: 'D':ambiguous inheritance of 'void A::Show(void)

Comment: What you are trying to do with `show`? What is the expected result? What is the actual result? If you are getting error messages, post them verbatim.

Comment: You show some code which, in itself, is OK. You need to show the *problem* you have!

Comment: That compiled fine in my machine (adding public to each show). What does the error say?

Comment: it says error C2550: 'D':ambiguous inheritance of 'void A::Show(void)'

Comment: 1. This error is 2250, not 2550. 2. Do you have `show` or `Show`? C++ is case sensitive.

Comment: ohhh thank you because `D` had `Show()` with little S it made the error,such a small misplace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of of you may want to make `show()` public.

Second, what is the ambiguity you talking about?

you should have no problem do this

```
D d;
d.show();
```

assuming `show()` is public now.

If you want to call `B::show()` or `C::show()`, use qualification.

Here is the sample code I had and run without problem.

```
    #include <iostream>
    class A
    {
            virtual void show()=0;
    };
    class B:public virtual A
    {
            void show(){/*content inside*/}
    };
    class C:public virtual A
    {
            void show(){/*content inside*/}
    };
    class D:public B,public C
    {
            public:
                    void show(){std::cout << "d\n";}
    };

    int main()
    {

            D d;
            d.show();
    }
```

Comment: yea i know just forgot it,i editted the error im getting if you know what that is

Comment: Thank you for replying,but i found the problem its is because D had the function written different from others(`show` was with small s others were big s)